# Django simple jwt authentication returning an weird error even if with default settings in settings.py file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Hello django simple jwt users, while implementing django simple jwt authentication token generation
I've encountered with an issue -
the default project configurations returning errors and asking
I am using python version 3.10 and latest version of simple jwt auth lib.

```
   from jwt import InvalidAlgorithmError, InvalidTokenError, algorithms

ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidAlgorithmError' from 'jwt'
```

To be exact this issue

```
ad Request: /api/user/r/
[01/Nov/2022 06:31:45] "POST /api/user/r/ HTTP/1.1" 400 62
Internal Server Error: /api/user/r/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "....../account/views.py", line 33, in post
    token = get_tokens_for_user(user)
  File "....../account/views.py", line 16, in get_tokens_for_user
    'refresh': str(refresh),
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py", line 81, in __str__
    return self.get_token_backend().encode(self.payload)
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py", line 204, in get_token_backend
    return self.token_backend
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py", line 197, in token_backend
    self._token_backend = import_string(
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/state.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .backends import TokenBackend
  File "....../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/backends.py", line 7, in <module>
    from jwt import InvalidAlgorithmError, InvalidTokenError, algorithms
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidAlgorithmError' from 'jwt' (....../jwt/__init__.py)
[01/Nov/2022 06:31:52] "POST /api/user/r/ HTTP/1.1" 500 159548
```

I have tried with different settings and different default settings by adding or removing them from my projects settings.py file , as mentioned in their project documentation
but not able to solve the issue

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

#manual refresh tokens
def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

this function causing this issue most probably
when it's called its causing the issue.

Now if you encounter with the same issue
how did you solve that
or inside init.py file InvalidAlgorithim error has to be put manually
then what will be the settings?
can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the package and python version.
I have tried with python2.7 it's working.
It seems to be deprecated or moved to the latest version of python.

[image]

Comment: Hey ajay thanks for you reply , I am using python 3.10 and latest package version of simple jwt . and I am fully aware of these what you have mentioned. My problem is not there my problem is , the error is a class error , and I have to implement that class inside __init__.py file of settings or main project package , what exactly will be the class specifications to overcome the issues, by the way thanks for your time

Comment: Hi Rajrup,

Check this link for more help.
https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/algorithms.html?highlight=InvalidAlgorithmError#specifying-an-algorithm